# Android studio 2.3 gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

When I started new project after updating android studio I was not able to solve the issue
please help be providing step by step on how to get rid of the problem !

Comment: please error log ?

Comment: what is the error? post the error log

Comment: "refresh failed", "the issue" and "the problem" are very vague descriptions of the situation. Can you provide more details?

Comment: no it's asking to re-download dependencies

Comment: in your gradle setting Offline mode is on or off ??@AshishJakhariya

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, was able to solve it, changing the JDK directory to the Java installation instead of using the Embedded JDK, that is changed at File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure

Project Structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue Yesterday and today I was able to solve it like this -

Go to this path C:\Users\user_name.gradle\wrapper\dists where user_name is your username if its you own PC or your company's name

Delete the latest gradle-****-all files since your latest update of android studio (i.e. 3.3 or another version).

If your android studio is open, close it then reopen it. A newer Gradle version will be downloaded.
(The Download size may be around 100-200  MB)

This should fix the issue.
Thank You!